# Need to make a code with def statements? & can't use global variables

Tags: python, function

I'm having issues with def statements. I can't seem to really seem to understand them. I have to make a code for class that's similiar to a casino slot machine. I have a code that'll do it, but not with def statements, which I need. I can't use global variables either. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
import random

money=''

b1=''

def greeting():

        print("Project 2")

def myMoney(money=0): 

    money=int(input("Let's play the slots!\nHow much money do you want to start with?\nEnter the starting number of dollars."))
    return money
    while True:
        if money>0:
            break
        if money==0:
            break


def getBet(bet=''):

        b1=int(input("How much do you want to bet?"))
        while True:
            if bet==0:
                break
            while True:
                if bet>money:
                    print("ERROR: You don't have that much left.")
                    print()
                    b1=int(input("How much do you want to bet?"))
                if bet<money:
                    input("Press enter to pull the slot machine handle!")
                    break
        return money
        return bet

    num1=random.randint(1, 5)
    num2=random.randint(1, 5)
    num3=random.randint(1, 5)
    print("/---+---+---\ ")
    print("|-"+str(num1)+"-|-"+str(num2)+"-|-"+str(num3)+"-|")
    print("\---+---+---/")

greeting()

myMoney()

getBet()
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  There are plenty of `def`s in what you posted.  What is the problem with your code?

Comment: I think he can't get it to work with input from the user

Comment: @BrenBarn: To me, the main problem seems to be he doesn't understand the `return` statement, and more generally, what a function is.

Comment: He's still using a global `money` for `getBet`.  He should be passing `money` as a variable to `getBet` rather than `bet`, since `getBet` is getting the bet.  Also, he's double returning from `getBet`...  He probably wants, `run_bet` instead of `getBet`, and doesn't need `myMoney` at all.

Comment: a `class` will be even better instead of passing around `money`

Comment: @John Y: Yeah, that could be the problem. I'm just kind of lost.

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on what functions are, what they do, how to use them and write them, etc. (The official Python tutorial has  [Defining Functions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions), but I think it's a bit too advanced for a new-programmer tutorial…)

Comment: The Python [wiki for beginners](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide) has a bunch of links that may be useful. If you need interactive advice (not real-time, but with periodic responses from real people), you could try the [python-tutor mailing list](http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/tutor). Many of the people there are used to working with complete beginners and have amazing patience. If you are helped by visualization, [this interactive code-stepper](http://www.pythontutor.com/) might be of use.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your "def statements" (functions) you can define variables as you need them. They won't be global

```
def A_function():
    money = 0
    #do all sorts of things
```

is basically equivalent to:

```
money=''
def Another_function(money=0):
    #do all sorts of things
```

which is what you have. See how with the first function I define the variable 'money' *inside* of the function? In the second one, you redefine the variable to be what you need. The end effect is the same, however, the first choice is preferred because it helps keep track of all the variables and doesn't define the variable globally. In your code, defining 'b1' and 'money' at the top is unnecessary because you already get a value from the input statements, located in each of your functions.